# Distributed tensor flow training with kubernetes

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, distributed-computing, kubeflow

I wanted to train a model using distributed tensor flow on my kubernetes cluster.
Please suggest ways other than kubeflow

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [TFX](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide), it supports both Airflow and kubeflow for scheduler, as Airflow also has KubernetesPodOperator itself.